# Timeout if no items are emitted after specified time

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have a simple operation where an api call is being performed and the result is an `Observable` which emits the response:

```
apiService.getTeam()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response>() {
          ...
    });
```

I'd like to provide some feedback to the user if no items are emitted after a few seconds. I am aware of the `.timeout()` operator, however this would be applied to each item, so even if a few items are emitted, a few seconds after the last available item is emitted the timeout would cause an error.

I would only like to timeout the operation if no items are emitted. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: check this http://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2016-03-16-retrofit2-rxjava-error-handling.html retrofit error handling.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `timeout` overload that you can use to timeout the first element and not timeout the rest:

```
Observable.never()
.timeout(() -> Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), e -> Observable.never())
.toBlocking()
.subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Here, the second parameter simply returns an Observable that will never emit and thus subsequent elements won't timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet can solve your problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean itemEmitted[] = { false };
    long identifier = -1l;
    Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .mergeWith(Observable.just(identifier).delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .map(v -> {
                if (!itemEmitted[0] && v == identifier) { // item is not emitted and a timeout occurs
                    throw new RuntimeException("timeout");
                }
                itemEmitted[0] = true;
                return v;
            }).filter(v -> v != identifier).toBlocking()
            .subscribe(v -> System.out.println(v));

}
```

`Observable.interval` is your source `Observable` that emits items which is merged with `Observable.just` with `delay` - whose combination acts similar to `timeout`. The output `Observable` is `map`ped to check if an actual item is emitted or whether timeout `identifier` occurred. If timeout, throw `Exception`. Later the output is `filter`ed to remove the identifier from the list of emitted items.

You can play with this code by modifying the value in initial `Observable.interval`.